# Codeigniter HMVC Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, hmvc

I need some help in my issue.
I have a list of users and I want to delete user onclick of delete button using ajax in CI HMVC. Here is code of my list view

```
$(function() {
    $(".tip-del").click(function() {
        var recId = $(this).data("id");
        var parent = $(this).parent();
        var BASE_URL = "<?php echo base_url()?>";
        var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this user?");
        if(r == true){
            $.ajax({
                url : BASE_URL + 'auth/delete_user',
                type: 'post',
                data: {'rec_id' : recId },
                success: function (response){
                    try{
                        if(response == 'true'){
                           parent.slideUp('slow',function(){$(this).remove();}); 
                        }
                    }catch(e) {     
                        alert('Exception while request..');
                    }                    
                },
                error: function (xhr, text, message) {
                    console.log(message);
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

And here is my controller(same module where the view is located) code

```
function delete_user() {
    if ($this->input->post('rec_id')) {
        $id = $this->input->post('id');
    }
    if (!$this->ion_auth->in_group('admin')) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->lang->line("access_denied"));
        $data['message'] = (validation_errors() ? validation_errors() : $this->session->flashdata('message'));
        redirect('module=auth&view=users', 'refresh');
    }
    $this->ion_auth_model->deleteUser($id);
}
```

And here is my model code

```
public function deleteUser($id) {
    if ($this->db->delete('users', array('id' => $id)) && $this->db->delete('users_groups', array('user_id' => $id))) {
        return true;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Can anybody please help me for this. I cant understand what I am going wrong. In a preview of ajax response I got the error as

```
An Error Was Encountered. The action you have requested is not allowed.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a line number and file associated with the error or is that the returned web view from codeigniter?

Comment: You check to make sure your db user has the proper permissions to perform delete(), that could be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think your delete query is wrong. It should be like below (in model code):

```
if ($this->db->where(array('id' => $id))->delete('users') && $this->db->where(array('user_id' => $id))->delete('users_groups')) {
        return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul, you solved my issue. Thank you very much.