# Failed to input data with jquery ajax on codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, onclick

I try to input data with ajax on codeigniter to check whether the data exists or not in my database, but the result always fails, even though the data is in my database table

View

```
<form id="form" method="post" class="form_user">
<input type="text" id="voucher" class="vchr form-control" name="vouchers">
<span class="input-group-btn">
<a class="vchr btn btn-info periksa" >Cek</a>
</span>
</form><script>


$(function(){
    $(".periksa").click(function(){
        var datas = $('#form').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "<?php echo base_url()?>userpage/cart/cekvoucher",
            data: datas,
            dataType:"json",
            cache : 'false',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#demo').html(data)
            },
            error: function(){
                alert('error ajax');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

controller

```
function cekvoucher(){
    $voucher = $this->input->post('vouchers');
    $where = array(
         'kode_voucher' => $voucher
        );
    $cek = $this->m_cart->cekvouch("voucher",$where)->num_rows();
    if($cek > 0){
        $data = "oke";
    }else{
        $data = "gagal";
    }

    echo json_encode($data);

}
```

model

```
`function cekvouch($table,$where){
        return $this->db->get_where($table,$where);
    }`
```

but

I check post result on variable $voucher is null and then i try comment $voucher and i use freeongkir to value kode_voucher and this is work, why this can happen?

```
function cekvoucher(){
//$voucher = $this->input->post('vouchers');
$where = array(
     'kode_voucher' => 'freeongkir'
    );
$cek = $this->m_cart->cekvouch("voucher",$where)->num_rows();
if($cek > 0){
    $data = "oke";
}else{
    $data = "gagal";
}

echo json_encode($data);}
```

Comment: have you checked the console for errors or response?

Comment: i already check in console tab chrome but i did not see any error

Comment: any type of response for your ajax??

Comment: in network tab show respon "gagal"

Comment: you have to check that your query returns any data or not. ```var_dump($cek); die;```, And check.

Comment: can u use `echo $this->db->last_query();` and check the query in phpmyadmin??

Answer (score 0):

You need to add index.php in your ajax url. try bellow ajax code working for me,

JQuery :

```
$(function(){
    $(".periksa").click(function(){
        var datas = $('#form').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "<?php echo base_url()?>/index.php/userpage/cart/cekvoucher",
            data: datas,
            dataType:"json",
            cache : 'false',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#demo').html(data)
            },
            error: function(){
                alert('error ajax');
           }
        });
    });
});
```

Hope this work for you.

Greetings!

Comment: make sure your url manner is: index.php/yourcontroller/yourmethod. what is userpage segment?

Comment: userpage is my modules, because i use HMVC

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26228533/codeigniter-hmvc-ajax. hope this will help you.